# mod_rewrite take part of url and add it to the end of a second url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am attempting to make it where faculty or students at my library that have a pmid number for PubMed, and want to share the link with others could do it by just remembering our url, and adding the pmid to the end of our url, with the identifier p.

This is where mod_rewrite comes in it would drop off the url: site.com/p/112233444 but keep 112233444 and then add it to the end of linkresolver.com/112233444

The rule that I have come up with is:

```
RewriteRule ^/p/(.*)$ linkresolver.com=$1
```

First, is this possible I control the library domain, but I am not in control of the second url that I am attempting to add the PMID to.

Second, this is my first attempt at mod_rewrite so if I am way let me know I have looked at Apache's documentation. I know it is really powerful complex tool, so my rewrite rule just seems off.

Any help would be greatl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ http://linkresolver.com/$1 [R]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no I am still getting just the site.com/p/112233444, and it is not rewriting the url

Comment: I take that back that made it work correctly. Thank you very much I didn't realize that you had removed that / in the /p/. Any reason that the leading / would make stop the redirect?

Comment: From the docs: "The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, **a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context**."